Programmatic way to switch apps in the mobile app
Is there any way to programatically switch between Salesforce apps on the mobile? F.ex. User is on the Account page in the Sales app and when they click quick action they are redirected to Account page in Service app.
I tried various approaches in LWC/AURA like NavigationMixin, e.force:switchApp, window.open(), etc.
They work on the desktop however none of them works on the mobile app.
